# Reading rows from Excel sheet to list of lists using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm new to Python and working on a Excel sheet that i want to read using python. I want to read the rows into lists of lists. I've tried this using Openpyxl

```
rows_iter = ws.iter_rows(min_col = 1, min_row = 2, max_col = 11, max_row = ws.max_row)

val1 = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in rows_iter]
```

But this gives me a single list of all the rows as lists inside.

I want to make make different lists consisting of 15 or 12 or 10 rows in them (depending on a condition).

Could you please help me.
Here are the sample Excel file, obtained output and expected outputs.[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7g20.png) and [obtained op](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP0iD.png). I'm not able to attach more than 2 attachments!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of a simple spreadsheet example, and your expected output and the output you're actually getting, to help clarify your question?

Comment: Glad I could help! If the answer given below worked for you, please click the check mark next to it to indicate your question has been answered. Also see [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to take a longer list of lists like `[list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6]`, and turn it into a group of lists of 2 lists `[[list1, list2]] [[list3, list4]] [[list5, list6]]`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly this is what i am looking for. The number of lists inside a list is dependent on the value present in a cell

Comment: That's a bit more tricky... :)

Comment: I'm working on it. But not able to generalize it. Now I am executing the same two lines with different min and max row numbers. It would be of great help if you could help me with it.

Comment: The question as posed was answered. I would suggest closing this question and spending some time working with the answer provided to try and modify it to do what you want. If you're still struggling with it, you can open a new question that's a little more specific.

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted so that others know what answer/information was useful. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
rows_iter = ws.iter_rows(min_col = 1, min_row = 2, max_col = 11, max_row = ws.max_row)

val_intermediate = [[cell.value for cell in list(row)] for row in rows_iter]

# This would be set to whatever cell value contains N
N = ws['A1'].value

# This splits your shallow list of lists into a list of N lists of lists (!)
val1 = [val_intermediate[j:j+N] for j in range(1,len(val_intermediate),N)]
```

**Explanation:** The first list comprehension will return a shallow list of lists. The second list comprehension converts your shallow list of lists into a group of lists of lists that are N entries long. To see how this works, consider this sample data:

```
In [1]: a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i'],['j','k','l'] ['m','n','o'],['p','q','r']]

In [2]: N=2; [a[j:j+N] for j in range(1,len(a),N)]

Out[2]:
[[['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']],
 [['j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n', 'o']],
 [['p', 'q', 'r']]]

In [3]: N=3; [a[j:j+N] for j in range(1,len(a),N)]

Out[3]:
[[['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']],
 [['m', 'n', 'o'], ['p', 'q', 'r']]]
```

The `range(1,len(a),N)` will create a sequence of integers from 1 to `len(a)`, skipping N numbers, so that's how you can pick the correct locations at which to split your shallow list of lists. It grabs N-1 items because of the `[j:j+N]` indexing.